# I want to use MsGraph in B2C, but I get a corrs error when getting an access token

Tags: api, cors, azure-ad-b2c, credentials

I have an SPA that uses B2C as its certification.
not AD, im using B2C.
Now I want to display user information on the SPA,
so I want to use MsGraphAPI to get data from B2C.
Therefore, we are trying to obtain an access token using credential flow.
The code is as follows

```
requestUri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenandId}/oauth2/v2.0/token";
var params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append("grant_type","client_credentials");
params.append("client_id","XXXX");
params.append("client_secret","ZZZZ");
params.append("scope","https://graph.microsoft.com/.default");

const response = fetch(requestUri, {
      method:"POST",
      body:params
});
```

At this time, the developer tool shows a corrs error.
The following error.

```
access to fetch "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenandId}/oauth2/v2.0/token" from origin "http://localhost:3000" has been blocked by CORS policy.
```

How can I resolve this?
SPA is available at http://localhost:3000.
Is the localhost no good?

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of authenticating is to get user information. You can insert any attribute into the token, and then parse the id_token to display the users profile information in your application. Calling MS Graph API for this seems counter intuitive.

Next, you shouldnt be using `client_credentials` in your SPA, those are secret credentails, and should only be used by your server. By exposing those credentials in your SPA, any user could extract them and use them to read your entire directroy store. This is why you are getting a CORS error, it's never supposed to be running on the client browser.

Comment: thank you for answer!
Of course, user information can be retrieved from the ID token. However, when user information is changed on the B2C side, it is not reflected in the ID token unless the user logs in again.
I want to get the changes in real time.

If we don't use client_credentials, which method would you suggest?
I would like to use graphAPI without the need for authentication on the part of the user. grant_type=authorization_code would require user interaction, which I would prefer not to use.

Comment: Have you considered using profile edit journey? This would then reflect into the token. If that is not an option, you need to use client credentials in your server app, eg node.js or .net API.

Comment: thank you for reply!And, sorry for my poor English.
"Profile Edit Journey" is custom policy?[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-profile-editing-policy?pivots=b2c-user-flow)

Also, I am using B2C for authentication, so I assume by server you mean Azure AD B2C(server app). So I am thinking that I cannot change the server side settings...

Comment: Profile edit journey can be either user flow or custom policy. By server, I mean your own api.